# How to test .promise() methods used in AWS built in methods in jest Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, jestjs, async.js

I want to unit test this completely the code for my function is given below

`function.js`

```
async function sesSendEmail(message) {
var ses = new aws.SES({ apiVersion: "2020-12-01" });
var params = {
    Source: "abc@gmail.com",
    Template: "deviceUsageStatisticsEmailTemplate",
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ["xyz@gmail.com"]
    },
    TemplateData: message,
}
try {
    let res = await ses.sendTemplatedEmail(params).promise()
    console.log(res)
}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

What i have tried in my tests so far:

`function.test.js`

```
test('should send templated email success', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
        const mData = {};
        ses.sendTemplatedEmail.mockImplementationOnce(async (params,callback) => {
            callback(null,mData)
        });
        const message = 'mock message';
        await index.sesSendEmail(message);
        expect(aws.SES).toBeCalledWith({ apiVersion: '2020-12-01' });
        expect(ses.sendTemplatedEmail).toBeCalledWith(
            {
                Source: 'abc@gmail.com',
                Template: 'deviceUsageStatisticsEmailTemplate',
                Destination: {
                    ToAddresses: ['xyz@gmail.com'],
                },
                TemplateData: message,
            },
        );
    await expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith(mData);
    });

    test('should handle error', () => {
        const arb = "network error"
        ses.sendTemplatedEmail = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            throw new Error(arb);
        })
        const message = 'mock message'
        expect(() => { index.sesSendEmail(message) }).toThrow(arb);
    });
});
```

**PROBLEM:**

It gives an error

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

- Expected
+ Received

- Object {}
+ [TypeError: ses.sendTemplatedEmail(...).promise is not a function],
```

I have tried variations in mockimplementations but to no avail.. any help/suggestion is highly appreciated :)

**UPDATE**

Tried requiring `aws-sdk-mock`

`aws.mock('ses','sendTemplatedEmail',function(callback){callback(null,mData)})`

but still getting error

`TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property ses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say mock the aws sdk itself and test your methods the way you normally do. Once such library is `aws-sdk-mock` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock)

Something like this

```
const sinon = require("sinon");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk-mock");

test("should send templated email success", async () => {
  const sendEmailStub = sinon.stub().resolves("resolved");
  AWS.mock("SES", "sendTemplatedEmail", sendEmailStub);
  const response = await sesSendEmail("{\"hi\": \"bye\"}");
  expect(sendEmailStub.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
  expect(sendEmailStub.calledWith(
    {
      "Source": "abc@gmail.com",
      "Template": "deviceUsageStatisticsEmailTemplate",
      "Destination": {
        "ToAddresses": ["xyz@gmail.com"]
      },
      "TemplateData": "{\"hi\": \"bye\"}"
    })).toEqual(true);
    expect(response).toEqual("resolved");
    AWS.restore();
});

test("should send templated email failure", async () => {
  const sendEmailStubError = sinon.stub().rejects("rejected");
  AWS.mock("SES", "sendTemplatedEmail", sendEmailStubError);
  const response = await sesSendEmail("{\"hi\": \"bye\"}");
  expect(sendEmailStubError.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
  expect(sendEmailStubError.calledWith(
    {
      "Source": "abc@gmail.com",
      "Template": "deviceUsageStatisticsEmailTemplate",
      "Destination": {
        "ToAddresses": ["xyz@gmail.com"]
      },
      "TemplateData": "{\"hi\": \"bye\"}"
    })).toEqual(true);
    expect(response.name).toEqual("rejected");
    AWS.restore();
});
```

Make sure from your original method, you are returning response and error.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPromisesDependency' of undefined

gives me this error when i try to require it

Comment: see this link - https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock/issues/110#issuecomment-523587036
Basically make sure you remove all other mocking on aws-sdk before you try this package.

Comment: you need to provide the function name only. without `.promise`

Comment: i guess `ses` need to be `SES`

Comment: I'm now getting the stub error on function.js part i don't understand why.. i'm a newbie to jest and aws-sdk-mocks in particular can you please write a sample for templated email success test ?

Comment: @AliKhan check my answer. Have added the code. hopefully this works.

Comment: Great!! but is there any reason why you used sinon ? and not just simple jest ? ( im not at all familiar with sinon.. btw much thanks :))

Answer (score 2):

`TypeError: ses.sendTemplatedEmail(...).promise is not a function` means that it expected the result of calling `ses.sendTemplatedEmail()` to be an object with a function property named `promise`.

To resolve this, you will need to return an object from your mock implementation that has the expected `promise` property. You will also need to remove the `async` keyword from your mock implementation as that would return a Promise object and not the expected object with `promise` property.

Here is an example that also returns a Promise object from `.promise()` as is expected by the production implementation of `sendTemplatedEmail.promise()`:

```
ses.sendTemplatedEmail.mockImplementationOnce((params,callback) => ({
  promise: () => Promise.resolve(callback(null,mData)),
}));
```